# How to run a JUnit test programatically and specify a classpath

Tags: java, junit5

I am writing a custom tool that executes a set of test classes programmatically using JUnit 5.

When executing these tests, is there a way to define the classpath for the execution? (I have a set of jars that are being provided, as well as some compiled production and test code which I will need to add to the classpath).

I have roughly the following code:

```
LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                                                                  .selectors(selectPackage(basePackage))
                                                                  .filters(includeClassNamePatterns(classNamePatterns))
                                                                  .build();

SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();

Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);

TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover(request);

// launcher.execute(request);
launcher.execute(testPlan);

TestExecutionSummary summary = listener.getSummary();
summary.printTo(new PrintWriter(System.out));
summary.printFailuresTo(new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: This depends on how you built your custom tool. If the tool is a shell script or can launch a shell script, you can compile then run this Test class with appended class path.

Comment: @ShankarPS: I'm looking to do this programatically so that the respective classpath can be valid just for the tests running in a `ClassLoader` and not affect the execution of other tests that may be running at the same time using a different classpath.

Answer (score 1):

When building the request you can select classpath roots via `org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClasspathRootSelector`.

Comment: Is this also applicable for production/test code under, for example, `target/classes` and, respectively, `target/test-classes`? Would you mind expaning your answer with a more detailed example?

Comment: Do you think you could provide a working illustration of how to do this? I need to be able to specify the classpath and location of the tests dynamically during runtime.